# How to select row or column from a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Here I have a matrix `a=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]])`

I want to select all rows, but the column I want to select is from the first to the third one.

It should be `[[1,2,3],[6,7,8],[11,12,13]]`

However, I have ever tried `a[:,[0,2]]`, but it shows

```
 array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 6,  8],
       [11, 13]])
```

It seems not the correct, so I tried another one a[:][0:2], it still is a wrong result.

So I want to ask if there are any function or method can fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `a[:, 0:3]`:

```
In [4]: a[:, 0:3]
Out[4]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [11, 12, 13]])
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want.

Comment: Great; if you found the answer helpful, you [can accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

I think need indexing `0:3`:

```
print (a[:,0:3])
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [11 12 13]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]])
a = a[:,0:3] 
print(a)
#Output
#array([[ 1,  2,  3],
#   [ 6,  7,  8],
#   [11, 12, 13]])
```